# PHP add product not working

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hello I am using php in conjunction with html and MySQL and need to add a product. The code itself is registering, but when I attempt to add a new product, nothing is being registered into the database. Maybe I'm just overlooking something small.

Here is my add_product function:

```
function add_product($productCode, $name, $version, $releaseDate) {
    global $db;
    $query = 'INSERT INTO products
             (productCode, name, version, releaseDate)
          VALUES
             (:productCode, :name, :version, :releaseDate)';
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':productCOde', $productCode);
    $statement->bindValue(':name', $name);
    $statement->bindValue(':version', $version);
    $statement->bindValue(':releaseDate', $releaseDate);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->closeCursor();
}
```

Here's my addproduct controller:

```
if ($action == 'add_product'){
//Get the IDs
$productCode = $_POST['productCode'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$version = $_POST['version'];
$releaseDate = $_POST['releaseDate'];
//register the product
add_product($productCode, $name, $version, $releaseDate);
}
```

And here is my add_product html:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" id="add_product_form">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_product">


    <label>Code:</label>
    <input type="text" name="productCode" />
    <br>

    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <br>

    <label>Version:</label>
    <input type="text" name="version" />
    <br>

    <label>Release Date:</label>
    <input type="text" name="releaseDate" />
    <br>

    <label>&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Product" />
    <br>
</form>
```

Comment: Easy, typo `productCOde`. I spotted that under 2 seconds flat ;-) exceptions would have too, had you been using that.

Comment: Maybe you should `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` to be able to see the PDO errors by yourself

Comment: If you're just learning about SQL and etc, right, cool. But for serious work, use some framework like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/), or at least a good [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) like [Doctrine2](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html).

Comment: Ive heard of laravel but never used it, and since my professor only gave us a couple days to do this, Ill hold off on learning that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if ($action == 'add_product'){`

Where do you set the value for $action?  Somewhere you need `$action = $_POST['action']` before the if statement.

Comment: They have it here `<input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_product">` but haven't defined it in their code. Least, not from what was posted. That, is just "one" of the errors made.

Comment: I hate answering questions from folks with just one point, and I get suckered in every time.  Do you think this guy will come back to review, comment and update info?  The rest of us would have created a local host server, stepped thru the code with a debugger and found the answer for ourselves, sigh.

Comment: Isn't it always the case? *sigh* I know it all too well.

Comment: Oh, wait. Is this a homework assignment?  Well if that's the case... Sigh... big sigh...

Comment: Maybe slip in a word about the typo they made in `':productCOde'` ;-) they're case-sensitive.

Comment: Hey I got it to work, it was mainly that typo but also I had to tweak one little thing in my code, thanks for the help zipit and fred

Comment: @triswill227    I was half joking when I mentioned this being a homework assignment.  I'm not half joking when I say, GET OFF YOUR BUTT, DO YOUR PROVEOUT ON A LOCALHOST SERVER, STEP THRU CODE WITH A DEBUGGER.  You will see errors immediately.  For a beginner project in php, Xdebug on a Xampp server will work with any number of free Integrated Development Environments (IDE), Eclipse will work fine.  PHPStorm is a very popular choice and I believe includes a complete server/debug kit, not sure what it costs for an educational license.